# Could I define a 'Interface' for 'Class' instead of 'Object' in java?

Tags: java, interface

We know 'interface' in java provide a common way to access objects who implementing it, but i wonder if there's a way like interface which not just for accessing the object's method, but also for accessing the class's method(static method). I want to use it to invoke an array of different classes's static factory method. Does java provide something like it?

Comment: Rather have a look on java reflection and probably you will get some solution which you are trying, although not sure what you want actually.

Comment: With Java 8, you can define static methods in interfaces, but they won't help you, because the have to be implemented in the interface class only using information you have there instead of relying on creation methods to be implemented by the subclasses, so your requirement will not be met.

Answer (score 3):

No.

But you can implement the pattern you describe easily with an ordinary object interface, then a set of classes that just wrap the static methods you wish to call through to.

Comment: thank u .  i want use the static factory method to create the object, so if use a wrapper method, there must have a object of the class before the target object construct. that's just a little strange....

Answer (score 3):

If your intentions is to call static method of an implementing class using Interface reference, the answer is No. static members belong to class only, so you will always need a Class type reference (actually it should be the class name) to access them.

With interfaces you can only point to what you have declared in it.

Comment: If you want to be extreme, then you can create a static class inside the interface with a static method. But even then, it will belong to the static class inside the interface, and not to the classes that implement the interface.

Comment: how come its extreme :)

Comment: I just never really ran into a use-case in which it was the logical solution. Of course, that's what I thought about many things that I eventually ended up doing or using, heh.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no kind of "interface for static methods" in Java.

(Aside from anything else, how would you expect to *specify* the class in question? Even generics wouldn't help here due to type erasure.)

Comment: thank u very much.

i have a common creater of some similar classes,  it receive a parameter('Class c').
now i use some 'if(c == OneClass.class)' to distinguish different class and invoke the static factory('return OneClass.staticFactory()').
i just want to find a simple way.  :)

Comment: @user3725479: Well if you know that all the classes you receive *will* have the relevant method, you can just invoke it with reflection. No compile-time safety, but it'll work...